# Как разделить дату от времени?

Tags: delphi, unixtimestamp, php

Имеется unixtimestamp (например: 1421279818 = **14.01.2015 23:56:58** UTC).
Нужно произвести изменения с временем, не трогая дату.

Алгоритмически так, например:

```
'14.01.2015' + ('23:56:58' * 20) и получить новые дату и время.
```

При умножении переполнение времени перейдёт в дополнительные дни ответа.
Если умножаем всё значение, естественно, ответ неверен, т.к. получается:

```
'14.01.2015 23:56:58' * 20
```

Переводим время в секунды и умножаем:

```
86218 * 20 = 1724360 = 19Д 22:59:20
```

Потом берем дату:

```
1421279818 - 86218 = 1421193600
```

Прибавляем результат:

```
1421193600 + 1724360 = 1422917960
```

Получаем **02.02.2015 22:59:20**

Вопрос в следующем: есть ли для таких вычислений что-то стандартное в Delphi либо Php или нужно своё изобретать?

В Delphi можно перевести, например, в DateTime, там разделить на составляющие, потом по отдельности их суммировать и следить за переполнениями дней/месяцев/лет, учитывать високосный год и прочее...

Проще, наверное, так и работать с unixtimestamp?

Comment: Для работы с датой есть [библиотека][1], которая позволяет производить разнообразные манипуляции с датой и временем.
[Тут на русском, не всё, но всё же][1].


  [1]: http://www.delphibasics.ru/navDateUtils.php

  [1]: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE7/en/DateUtils_%28Delphi%29

Comment: Это мне, конечно, известно, там на много больше функций, но всё для работы с TDateTime, а не с unixtimestamp, только 2 имеется для перевода туда/назад DateTimeToUnix и наоборот... но с TDateTime неудобно работать, как я уже писал выше

Comment: http://platonov-andrei.narod.ru/Delphi/DateTimeUtil.htm

Answer (score 1):

А зачем менять само данное? Можешь просто представить, как тебе нужно с помощью функции `Date()`.

Здесь все про эту функцию расписано: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

Вот так, например, можно отобразить только лишь дату (без времени):

```
Date ('d/m/Y',timestamp);
```

Comment: Отобразится то оно отобразится, а операции будут с ними корректно производиться? Это же только для визуализации, как я понимаю... Сам timestamp останется неизменным

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php

Comment: @Isaev записываешь результат этой функции в переменную и делай с этой переменной что хочешь. Сам timestamp менять и не надо. Ты в любое время можешь его представить в любом виде благодаря функции `Date ()`

Answer (score 0):

Умножаем на 20, это на дни?

Используйте

```
date('d.m.Y', strtotime($time.' + 20 Days'));
```

Comment: @Сергей Баранов, нет, это не на дни, это на 20... т.е. ускоряем время в 20 раз

Comment: @Isaev ээээ.... "ускоряем время в 20 раз"? Вы явно что-то не так делаете. Расскажите, для чего вам это нужно.
Если есть какой-то промежуток времени между двумя таймстампами и его нужно увеличить/уменьшить, то эта задача решается намного проще.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, да всё было проще, разобрался, реализовал... Как обычно, слишком сложно думал)

Comment: @Isaev запишите свою реализацию как ответ и примите его как верный.